# How to build SOIL on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, makefile, soil

I'm relatively inexperienced with the workings of downloading, making, and linking libraries, and I was hoping to get SOIL (Simple OpenGL Image Library) so that I can use it in Xcode (newest version) on Mac OS X El Capitan with OpenGL 3.3 and GLFW in C++. (link: http://www.lonesock.net/soil.html, download: http://www.lonesock.net/files/soil.zip) I downloaded the zip, but I wasn't sure how to go from there.

I tried cd'ing to the entire folder in terminal and typing "make", along with "make -f makefile", and even adding a line I found in a previous response to the makefile, but nonetheless I wasn't sure how to do it. Would anyone be able to describe how to build it in detail?

Comment: Hmmm... (July 7, 2008) is the "latest" version? There's likely a more modernized version on github. Lots of things have changed in OS X since 2008, so you'd probably be better off using something more current.

Comment: Well I was following this handy tutorial for OpenGL, "http://learnopengl.com/#!Introduction" and that tutorial linked to this version. There are comments on the tutorial that are newer, but he links to that version. Link is in the middle of this page: "http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures"

Comment: Take a look at this comment: they mention an updated version, so hope that helps :) http://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Textures#comment-2185618271 (github project here: https://github.com/smibarber/libSOIL)

Comment: The `zip` has an unusual structure.  There seem to be build recipes for various architectures in `projects`; in `projects/makefile` there is a `makefile`   and also another file called `alternate Makefile.txt` -- you could try `make -f ../projects/makefile/makefile` in `src` but that's just a quick shot.

Comment: l'L'l, that github project worked great! I had to add sudo to their instructions, but it worked. Thanks!